# Create Image From A Binary File?

Tags: c#, bitmap, jpeg, rgb, cmyk

I Need help to create an image preview from A Riped Binary File in C#.

The File Having the Following information in first 48 byte.

> nSignature;  //        0x1234 (DATA in 4-byte )
>
> nXDPI;  //        Image        XDPI (DATA in 4-byte )
>
> nYDPI; //        Image        YDPI (DATA in 4-byte )
>
> nBytesPerLine; //1 Line Data Length /Byte (DATA in 4-byte )
>
> nHeight;  //Image      Height (DATA in 4-byte )
>
> nWidth;  //Image      Width (DATA in 4-byte )
>
> nPaperWidth;  //No Use. 25: CaoXueShi (DATA in 4-byte )
>
> nColors;   //1=monochrome         4: CMYK (DATA in 4-byte )
>
> nBits;   //No Use for most printer //Techwin: PassNum (DATA in 4-byte
>   )
>
> nReserved[3]; //0: Pass Number, 1: vsdMode //DWORD VsdMode;(DATA in
>   12-byte )

after the 48 byte information the color information stored.

> First line
>
> KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
>
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
>
> MMMMMMMMMMMM
>
> YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
>
> Second line
>
> KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
>
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
>
> MMMMMMMMMMMM
>
> YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY ….

the **nBytesPerLine** define the number of byte in each line  that is how many bytes for k ,c,m and y.

and the **nHeight** define the numbers of line of color information.

now using  the above information i want to create an image preview in C#

You may download a binary file from here 
[Download](https://app.box.com/s/aau8hviav8r3tn1znge5)

Please Help

Comment: What is the question? What have you done so far?

Comment: `i want to create an image preview in C#` So go ahead and create! :)

Comment: Good luck I hope it's the best image preview ever!

Answer (score 2):

Hi Every One Finally solve my Problem

First OF All Create A Class File RGB

```
using System; 
using System.ComponentModel;
    namespace CMYK_RGB
    {

        public struct RGB
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets an empty RGB structure;
            /// </summary>
            public static readonly RGB Empty = new RGB();

            #region Fields
            private int red;
            private int green;
            private int blue;

            #endregion

            #region Operators
            public static bool operator ==(RGB item1, RGB item2)
            {
                return (
                    item1.Red == item2.Red 
                    && item1.Green == item2.Green 
                    && item1.Blue == item2.Blue
                    );
            }

            public static bool operator !=(RGB item1, RGB item2)
            {
                return (
                    item1.Red != item2.Red 
                    || item1.Green != item2.Green 
                    || item1.Blue != item2.Blue
                    );
            }

            #endregion

            #region Accessors
            [Description("Red component."),]
            public int Red
            {
                get
                {
                    return red;
                }
                set
                {
                    red = (value>255)? 255 : ((value<0)?0 : value);
                }
            }

            [Description("Green component."),]
            public int Green
            {
                get
                {
                    return green;
                }
                set
                {
                    green = (value>255)? 255 : ((value<0)?0 : value);
                }
            }

            [Description("Blue component."),]
            public int Blue
            {
                get
                {
                    return blue;
                }
                set
                {
                    blue = (value>255)? 255 : ((value<0)?0 : value);
                }
            }
            #endregion

            public RGB(int R, int G, int B) 
            {
                red = (R>255)? 255 : ((R<0)?0 : R);
                green = (G>255)? 255 : ((G<0)?0 : G);
                blue = (B>255)? 255 : ((B<0)?0 : B);
            }

            #region Methods
            public override bool Equals(Object obj) 
            {
                if(obj==null || GetType()!=obj.GetType()) return false;

                return (this == (RGB)obj);
            }

            public override int GetHashCode() 
            {
                return Red.GetHashCode() ^ Green.GetHashCode() ^ Blue.GetHashCode();
            }

            #endregion
        } 
    }
```

Now Create A Window Form And Add picturbox,label,Filedailog and A Button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int size = -1;
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Open Prt File";

            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                label1.Text = file;
                try
                {
                    FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@file);
                    byte[] NumberOfByteprLine = new byte[4];
                    byte[] NumberOfLineInImage = new byte[4];


                    byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    stream.Close();

                    int j = 19;
                    Int64 decValue;
                    decValue = buffer[j--] * 256 * 256 * 256;
                    decValue += buffer[j--] * 256 * 256;
                    decValue += buffer[j--] * 256;
                    decValue += buffer[j--];
                    Int32 ImageHeight = Convert.ToInt32(decValue);

                    j = 15;
                    decValue = buffer[j--] * 256 * 256 * 256;
                    decValue += buffer[j--] * 256 * 256;
                    decValue += buffer[j--] * 256;
                    decValue += buffer[j--];
                    Int32 NumberOfBytePerLine = Convert.ToInt32(decValue);

                    j = 23;
                    decValue = buffer[j--] * 256 * 256 * 256;
                    decValue += buffer[j--] * 256 * 256;
                    decValue += buffer[j--] * 256;
                    decValue += buffer[j--];
                    Int32 ImageWidth = Convert.ToInt32(decValue);

                    string hexXResValue = string.Empty, hexYResValue = string.Empty;
                    for (int i = 11; i > 3; i--)
                    {
                        if (i > 7)
                        {
                            hexYResValue = hexYResValue + Convert.ToInt64(buffer[i]).ToString("X");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hexXResValue = hexXResValue + Convert.ToInt64(buffer[i]).ToString("X");
                        }
                    }

                    //Int32 ImageWidth = int.Parse(hexWValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                    //Int32 ImageHeight = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

                    Int32 XResolution = int.Parse(hexXResValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                    Int32 YResolution = int.Parse(hexYResValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

                    Int64 StartByte = 48;

                    int width = NumberOfBytePerLine, hieght = ImageHeight;
                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, hieght);
                    int value = 0;
                    for(int i=0; i<ImageHeight;i++)
                    {

                        for (Int32 k = 0; k < NumberOfBytePerLine; k++)
                        {


                            decValue = buffer[StartByte];
                            string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");

                            int Y = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

                            decValue = buffer[StartByte + NumberOfBytePerLine];
                            hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");

                            int M = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

                            decValue = buffer[StartByte + NumberOfBytePerLine*2];
                            hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");

                            int C = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

                            decValue = buffer[StartByte + NumberOfBytePerLine*3];
                            hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");

                            int K = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);


                             RGB rgb = CMYKtoRGB((double)C / 100.0, (double)M / 100.0, (double)Y / 100.0, (double)K / 100.0);

                            StartByte++;

                            bmp.SetPixel(k, i, Color.FromArgb(rgb.Red, rgb.Green, rgb.Blue));


                            value++;

                        }

                        StartByte = StartByte + (NumberOfBytePerLine * 3);

                    }


                    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                    string Path = "C:\\Users\\Abhishek Singh\\Desktop\\PrtFile\\prtfiles\\imageFile.bmp";

                    bmp.Save(Path);


                }
                catch { }
            }
        }



         /// <summary>
        /// Converts CMYK to RGB.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c">Cyan value (must be between 0 and 1).</param>
        /// <param name="m">Magenta value (must be between 0 and 1).</param>
        /// <param name="y">Yellow value (must be between 0 and 1).</param>
        /// <param name="k">Black value (must be between 0 and 1).</param>
        public static RGB CMYKtoRGB(double c, double m, double y, double k)
        {
            int red = Convert.ToInt32((1.0 - c) * (1.0 - k) * 255.0);
            int green = Convert.ToInt32((1.0 - m) * (1.0 - k) * 255.0);
            int blue = Convert.ToInt32((1.0 - y) * (1.0 - k) * 255.0);

            return new RGB(red, green, blue);
        }
```

[image: Output Screen]

[Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19045/Manipulating-colors-in-NET-Part)